# Python; Retreving dictonary values with more than one index

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to retrieve a message from a dictionary based off a value (foo); the problem I'm facing is that I have more than one index for each message. It is proving to be difficult to retrieve the same message when the index changes value. I know this may not make all that much sense, but I hope by looking at the code it will help.

```
foo=int(input('What is foo'))#foo is always 1 to 10
bar={10:'10/10',
 (8 or 9):'message1',
 (6 or 7):'message2',
 (4 or 5):'message3',
 (2 or 3):'message4',
 (0 or 1):'message5',
print(bar[foo])
```

This code is part of a larger program it is just with this part that I can't solve. Foo is predetermined so the user doesn't input it in the overall program. I have tried multiple fixes for this problem and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That goes also for 8

Comment: sorry that was a a typo when putting it on here

Comment: Are your multiple indices always consecutive numbers?  Or could you conceivably have an entry: `(2 or 8): 'messageX', ...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use a single integer as a key, you could use math to simplify each key to a single unique value, for example

```
bar = {5:'10/10',     # 10
       4:'message1',  # 9 or 8
       3:'message2',  # 7 or 6
       2:'message3',  # 5 or 4
       1:'message4',  # 3 or 2
       0:'message5'}  # 1 or 0

>>> foo = 7
>>> bar[foo // 2]
'message2'
```

Comment: Thanks thats a really good soultion, I've taken the liberty of changing the last part to: print(bar[int(foo/2)])

Comment: @MunchingLemon Why? `foo//2` has been part of the language since Python 2.2

Comment: @MunchingLemon not to mention that `/` will possibly return `float`s in Python 3, so it won't work.... `//` will always return an `int` which is what you want...

Comment: This is the best answer (including mine), assuming that the multiple keys will always be consecutive integers, as in the sample data.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of solving this. You can put some dictionary values in multiple times.
However if you really want composite keys, you can store the keys of the dictionary as 2-tuples (10 as a 1-tuple). Then you can first retrieve the key in which foo is stored:

```
foo = int(input('What is foo'))
bar = {(10,):'10/10',
 (8, 9):'message1',
 (6, 7):'message2',
 (4, 5):'message3',
 (2, 3):'message4',
 (0, 1):'message5'}
print(bar[foo])

key = next(k for k in bar.keys() if foo in k)
```

and then retrieve the values:

```
print(bar[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat values in the dictionary with different keys.

```
bar={10:'10/10',
    9: 'message1',
    8:'message1',
    7:'message2',
    6:'message2',
    5:'message3',
    4:'message3',
    3:'message4',
    2:'message4',
    1:'message5',
    0:'message5',
    }
```

or

```
select = {9: 8,
          7: 6,
          5: 4,
          3: 2,
          1: 0}

foo = select.get(foo, foo) # If the value isn't found return the original value

bar={10:'10/10',
    8:'message1',
    6:'message2',
    4:'message3',
    2:'message4',
    0:'message5',
    }

 print(bar[foo])
```

or use math.l

Answer (score 0):

All the solutions here work.  What I can't tell from the OP is whether you might have a message with a key like `(2 or 9)` (you didn't show it in your sample data, but doesn't necessarily mean you don't need it).  With the exception of the solution suggesting the repeating of values with different keys, none of these will work for that use case.

First, save your indices as tuples:

```
>>> bar = {(10,): '10/10',
...        (8, 9): 'message1',
...        (6, 7): 'message2',
...        (4, 5): 'message3',
...        (2, 3): 'message2',
...        (0, 1): 'message1',}
```

This will allow you to reference them fairly easily.  Next, iterate through your keys, searching for `foo` in the keys and grab the message, when you find it:

```
>>> for key in bar.keys():
...     if foo in key:
...         message = bar[key]
...         break
...
>>>
```

The complete solution is:

```
>>> bar = {(10,): '10/10',
...        (8, 9): 'message1',
...        (6, 7): 'message2',
...        (4, 5): 'message3',
...        (2, 3): 'message2',
...        (0, 1): 'message1',}
>>>
>>> foo = 6
>>>
>>> for key in bar.keys():
...     if foo in key:
...         message = bar[key]
...         break
...
>>> assert message == 'message2'
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have already a working answer, since your special case allow for a simple arithmetic expression  on the retrieval to work around for you. However, in the general case, the solution to this is to use an specialized mapping class,  which serves exactly the purpose of a "multi-key" dictionary.

There is no such data structure by default in Python's stdlib, but there are a couple different (and nice) implementations on the Python Package Index. In general, you just seacr pypi.python.org for "multi key dictionary", pick a module from the highest-rated, and either add it to you project's requirements, or install it directly with "pip install ".

The idea of such a multi-key dictionary is not something difficult to implement - just implement the appropriate methods listed for the interface (Abstract Base Class) of "mutable mapping" in a class that does the job. In general "the job" will involve having one or more inner aggregated dictionaries.

For example:

```
from collections import MutableMapping
# (Collections.abc in Python 3.x)

class MDict(MutableMapping):
def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    self._data = {}
    self._keys = {}
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    if not hasattr(key, "__iter__") or not hasattr(key, "__len__"):
         key = (key,)
         self._keys[key] = key
    else:
         key = tuple(key)
    for component in key:
        self._keys[component] = key
    self._data[key] = value
def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self._data[self._keys[key]]
# Implement the other methods specified for MutableMapping:
# __delitem__, __iter__, __len__ 
# and other nice thigns to have (like def add_key(existing_key, newkey),
# delkey..
```

Comment: I've been downvoted with no justificative, but I maintain that as of now this is the best answer so far (among the others listed here) for "Retreving dictonary values with more than one index" - and not fit just for the O.P. specific case.